# PHP Class Inheritance and extending methods

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I want to accomplish the following, but I'm not sure how to do it:

```
class foo {
    function doSomething(){
        // do something
    }
}

class bar extends foo {
    function doSomething(){
        // do something AND DO SOMETHING ELSE, but just for class bar objects
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this while still using the `doSomething()` method, or do I have to create a new method?

Edit: To clarify, I do not want to have to restate 'do something' in the inherited method, I just want to state it once in the foo->doSomething() method and then build upon it in child classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it right there. If you want to call `doSomething()` in `foo`, simply do this in `bar`:

```
function doSomething() {
    // do bar-specific things here
    parent::doSomething();
    // or here
}
```

And the restating a method you mention, is commonly referred to as overloading.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`parent`](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) keyword:

```
class bar extends foo {
    function doSomething(){
        parent::doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When extending a class you can simply use `$this->method()` to use the parent-method, as you have not overwritten it. When you have overwritten it, the snippet will point to the new method. You can access the parent-method via `parent::method()` then.